# CloudFlare Orange Cloud // Extension

Tags: cloud, cloudflare

I'm getting an error where when I visit my site https://www.leapcraft.net I get 2 /s at the end of the URL. As it's not affecting the content within the website it's not to big of a deal but it's a weird bug that I want to solve.

I've tried editing the nginx.conf and the VirtualHost File. I also set CloudFlare SSL to Full(Strict)

I should be seeing https://www.leapcraft.net but I see https://www.leapcraft.net//

Answer (score 0):

This is because of you have a 301 redirection setup somewhere to explicitly redirect visitors to `https://www.leapcraft.net//` possibly in Cloudflare Page Rules, webserver configs (nginx.conf, httpd.conf etc) or .htaccess

```
$ curl -svo /dev/null leapcraft.net 2>&1 | grep "Location:"
< Location: https://www.leapcraft.net//
$ curl -svo /dev/null www.leapcraft.net 2>&1 | grep "Location:"
< Location: https://www.leapcraft.net//
$ curl -svo /dev/null http://www.leapcraft.net 2>&1 | grep "Location:"
< Location: https://www.leapcraft.net//
```

Comment: I actually don't I've gone through nginx.conf, the virtualhost, and a .htaccess that I have in there only for an error document even then I just put that in my webserver config. And I just checked there's no page rules.